# Bug occurs in HTML video tag on mobile

Tags: html

No errors or warnings appear in the console.

**html**

```html
 <div class="subimg" id="teaching_video_div" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none; align-items: center; overflow: hidden">
       <video id="teaching_video" type="video/mp4" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid black" controls muted loop playsinline></video>
</div>
```

**js**

```js
const teachingVideoObject = document.getElementById('teaching_video');
const videoSrc = `../../common/images/pilates/Act/${actList[actIndex]['ex_cd']}/demo.mp4`;
if (teachingVideoObject.src !== videoSrc) {
     teachingVideoObject.src = videoSrc;
     teachingVideoObject.load();
}
```

In a mobile environment, when double-clicking the video to skip 10 seconds or go back, the video restarts from the beginning.
However, if the video URL is set to a remote URL instead of a local file, this bug does not occur.
Can you identify what might be causing this issue?
I apologize for my limited English proficiency.